# "A ruleset parameter of type XML is not supported in a JSON payload" exception when using the Business Rules service on Bluemix

Tags: business-rules, ibm-cloud

I tried to use my XML data with the HTDS REST JSON API and I got the exception:

```
 "A ruleset parameter of type XML is not supported in a JSON payload"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to use the XML binding object model, which is not supported in the JSON format. 
Once I switched to the XML format, the error disappeared.